# Referencing image stored in public_html folder live server

Tags: php, laravel, image, cpanel

I'm keeping my images in the *PUBLIC* folder instead of using storage as the images are not sensitive. I've deployed the laravel app to a live server but the images are now transferred into the **public_html** folder instead of public. The images aren't displaying. I tried creating a symlink.php file but i think those are use to reference when using the storage folder right? It's my first time deploying a web btw. Thanks in advance.

**Controller (I'm uploading image to the public/img/news folder)**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    if($request->filename){
        $name=time().'.'.explode('/',explode(':',substr($request->filename,0,strpos($request->filename,';')))[1])[1];

    \Image::make($request->filename)->save(public_path('img/news/').$name);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that stores the images? You are probably using a wrong folder there.

Comment: Provide a code from the controller where you store your images please.

Comment: <img class="d-block mx-auto" :src="'/img/news/' + newz.image_name" height="300px">  ,,, plus im using laravel with vue@Jerodev

Comment: check update. thanks @zlatangoralija